# Pulling out of a cut on a table saw

Tags: joinery

I recognise that this is a very elementary question but I’m new to table saws and no amount of googling has given me an answer to my question (I’m probably using the wrong terms). I want to cut a half lap joint on the end of some 4 by 2. Quite a long piece. What I think I will need to do is a 2 inch cut, pull the work piece back off the blade. Flip it upside down so that I can then complete the cut on the other side (as the blad is not tall enough to cut the full four inches.

My question, is pulling the workpiece back off the blade seen as being dangerous? I assume it is but then how do you make a cut when you don’t want to rip the full length of a plank?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. And kudos for not going ahead with something that might be sketchy on the TS! That's one of the first steps in not becoming complacent about its use; always remember the table saw is *the* most dangerous power tool in the workshop and responsible for the most frequent serious injuries and worse.

Comment: If I might suggest, the thing to have searched for when you failed to find what you were looking for was something like "half laps on the table saw" or just "lap joints table saw" because then you'd have found what you actually needed — laps *are* routinely cut on the TS, just not in the way you were visualising. There are two main methods, but the simpler is to nibble away at the end of the board cut by cut until the wood is removed, the board held securely to an extended mitre guage, or better, using a sled. The joint face is then usually cleaned up slightly, but not for rough work.

Comment: P.S. Now might be a good time to make a crosscutting sled :-) You'll use it *loads*. We have a couple of old Answers here on these and there are about a bazillion sled videos on YouTube, but so many designs are waaay too elaborate for most users, and the sleds are large/unwieldy and just too darned heavy. So I advise starting with a very simple, smallish, one to begin with and seeing how you get on with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a table saw is the wrong tool for this job.  Trying to precisely manipulate a large piece of wood is always tricky; you can easily slip and damage the workpiece or you.

What I would do is:

- Clamp the long piece of 2x4 to a work bench.
- Repeatedly cut across the 2x4 with a circular saw set to very slightly less than the depth you want to remove.
- Knock out the waste wood with a chisel
- Lay a couple of pieces of scrap 2x4 next to the workpiece, and use a router to precisely finish off the joint.

The hand-tools version of the above is using a tenon saw to make the cross cuts, and then a chisel to pare down to the exact depth. I might well do the paring down with a chisel even now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate your response. I do have a router and circular saw so I will try that approach. As you say, probably easier to work with given the length of wood. Thanks again!

Comment: +1, though in desperation, one might simply turn off the saw and wait for it to spin down before moving the wood off the saw. Be sure that the wood isn't going to move even a fraction (which is extra hard with long pieces), as that's a recipe for a projectile.

Comment: And just to reinforce, "pulling the workpiece back" (quote from the OP) is literally the worst thing possible.

Answer (score 2):

> is pulling the workpiece back off the blade seen as being dangerous?

It could be, depending on how far you've cut. The problem is that when you rip a board some distance, tension in the wood can cause the cut to close up. If that happens, and you pull the board back toward you, the rising teeth at the back of the blade can grab the board and throw it back at you. That's a kickback, and if the board hits you it can do real damage.

> What I think I will need to do is a 2 inch cut, pull the work piece back off the blade. Flip it upside down so that I can then complete the cut on the other side

A two inch cut should be fine. A cut through the thickness of a 2x4 isn't going to close up in just two inches. Also, if you only cut two inches, the end of the workpiece isn't going to reach the back of the blade, so those back teeth won't be in contact with the workpiece.

> how do you make a cut when you don’t want to rip the full length of a plank?

If you were proposing a longer cut, where the end of the workpiece would go significantly beyond the back of the blade, then a safe option would be to cut as far as you want and then shut the saw off. Once the blade comes to a stop, you can remove the workpiece, flip it, and finish the cut.

Also, you should always use either a blade guard or a riving knife. A guard won't work for a cut that doesn't go all the way through the workpiece, so use a riving knife instead. Both options can help prevent kickbacks.

All that said, you're going to run into a few issues:

1. If you're making a half-lap joint, you'll want to cut exactly along the center line of the workpiece. That means you'll set the distance between the rip fence and the right side of the blade (assuming the rip fence is on the right) to exactly half the thickness of the 2x4, so that the kerf ends up on the waste side of the line. However, when you flip the workpiece over to make the second half of the cut, the kerf will be on the wrong side of the line, so you'll need to move the fence by exactly the kerf width so that the left side of the blade cuts along the center line.
2. The blade is obviously circular, so if you cut two inches from both sides, the center of the board will have been missed. Use a hand saw to cross cut the waste (because it's awkward to cross cut a very long piece on a table saw), but the waste piece will still hold on in the center. Break it out, and the cleach up the rest with a chisel.
3. If the workpiece is very long, it can be hard to keep it firmly against the rip fence. Use a [featherboard](https://www.table-saw-guide.com/featherboard.html) to help you, and also some infeed support.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to take a stab at the question in the title rather then the description, for helping people that have a different use case that requires making stopped cuts on the table saw.

As mentioned in comments and the other answer, a stopped cut on a table saw does posed increased risk of kickback. There are two ways I can imagine a stopped cut being done:

1. The piece is fed through the saw until the desired cut depth is reached, then pulled back out. This really is dangerous as it is hard to keep the piece from fractionally angling between the fence and the blade. This can very quickly catch the piece on the spinning blade and cause a kickback.
2. Once the cut is made, the saw is turned off and the piece is moved only when the saw blade has come to a full stop. This is somewhat safer (as the piece can still be held tight against the fence), but still riskier than a regular cut. This obviously also takes quite a long time (most saws take many seconds to fully stop) and would temp the user to use method #1 instead.

To sum up, a table saw is not the best tool for making stopped cuts (a band saw immediately springs to mind for that), but it can be done at the increased risk of kickback.

Comment: The saw blade can be stopped more quickly by poking a bit of scrap wood in the blade.  Of course, the main work piece must continue to be held steady when this is done - this may be a task for a careful assistant.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica — if the careful assistant is on the wrong side of the blade (as they would naturally be if a careful operator was holding the work steady) and stuck a piece of wood into the blade, they’d probably create a projectile that hits the careful operator. I’d suggest you either expand on your idea to describe it safely, or reconsider.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I don't think anybody in their right mind would "poke a bit of scrap wood" into a spinning blade. That sounds far more dangerous than simply reversing the direction of the cut. Any material introduced to the blade should be guided by either the rip fence or a miter gauge or sled.

Comment: In general, it's not at all "hard to keep the piece from fractionally angling between the fence and the blade." The whole point of the rip fence is to support and guide the workpiece in a straight line parallel to the blade, and the saw doesn't care whether you're moving toward the blade or away from it. The main danger comes from a through cut that's long enough that a) it extends beyond the back of the blade, and b) lets the cut close up due to stress in the board, so that the back of the blade might grab the wood if you pull it back.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a table saw, if you have access to a sliding mitre saw with a depth stop that would be an easier to manage and safer option. Google mitre saw trench cutting. As previously mentioned, a circular saw is also a reasonable approach.

Cheers

Comment: A mitre saw will work, but there's a big issue here in that mitre saws/chop saws are one of the least-useful tools to add to a workshop. Many pros don't own one, and a few who did at some point ditched theirs when they came to the realisation of how little unique use there is for one..... along with the ever-problematical infeed/outfeed space requirement.